# Get comment from TextLine

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have

```
var sourceText = SourceText.From(filestream);
var firstLine = sourceText.Lines.FirstOrDefault();
```

which give me first line of source as TextLine. I need to parse comment as string, but i would like to use Roslyn for that. How can i extract single line comment from TextLine using Roslyn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the text into a syntax tree, then search for trivia of the kind you want. You have several syntax kinds, including `SingleLineCommentTrivia, MultiLineCommentTrivia, ...`:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceText, path: filename);
var root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();

var comment = root.DescendantTrivia()
    .OfType<SyntaxTrivia>()
    .FirstOrDefault(s=> s.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia)) // Here you decide what you want to filter on
    .ToFullString();
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxkind?view=roslyn-dotnet for more details